# Which solution to represent large results?

Tags: java

I'm working on source code analysis of the linux Kernel considering all the 2.6 versions...

I'm collecting results for each file compiled and for each version of the kernel...

So far, i'm using an ad-hoc format and then I analyze the data with a small python script (a typical result file is about 300MB)...

However, an ad-hoc is not really convenient, because it's hard to interpret the data, and not really flexible, since as soon as you change the format, your interpretation script must be modified too...

I would like something that can easily evolve and from which i can easily extract some information...

Which solution is the best in my case to represent the results ?

- ad hoc format ?
- XML ?
- DataBase ? (if so which engine ?)
- Google AppEngine ?

PS: i'm using Java 1.5.

Comment: In any case, be it XML,Database, whatnot, if you change the format(e.g. adding another column in a DB table) you'd have to adjust the interpretation script.

Representing data encoded with XML can be very verbose and self explainig, But you'd ofcourse need to know what the XML data means, an XML parser only get you so far. (and with XML comes overhead, in large quantities usually).

If you're always interpreting the data in python; output Python data structures!. No parsing would be needed by your script, parsing python data structures isn't that hard in another language.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first comment from Oscar isn't too bad. Maybe you should rethink your format and the way of analyzing it. I wrote several ad hoc formats for analyzing data, too, just to realize that a different data structure (in my case a simple binary tree) could do the same task in seconds instead of minutes. Most of the time, a database might be the best solution and for a plain old Java Program you might consider [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) as the most convenient solution.